# Развернуть сервер

Tags: c#, linux, .net

Создал droplet в DigitalOcean для своего сервера. Установил туда MySQL базу. Все хорошо работает, но вот .NET SDK не хочет не как ставится. Вроде бы устанавливается, а вроде нет. Ошибки не какие не пишет. Просто ввожу команду:

```
dotnet --info
```

И пишет что он не установлен. Я даже использовал официальный скрипт sh от microsoft. Где было написано что successfully установлено .NET SDK

```
root@server:~# ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest
dotnet-install: Attempting to download using aka.ms link https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.414/dotnet-sdk-6.0.414-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Remote file https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.414/dotnet-sdk-6.0.414-linux-x64.tar.gz size is 186224870 bytes.
dotnet-install: Extracting zip from https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.414/dotnet-sdk-6.0.414-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Downloaded file size is 186224870 bytes.
dotnet-install: The remote and local file sizes are equal.
dotnet-install: Installed version is 6.0.414
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/root/.dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
dotnet-install: Note that the script does not resolve dependencies during installation.
dotnet-install: To check the list of dependencies, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install, select your operating system and check the "Dependencies" section.
dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.
```

Все равно пишет, что не установлен SDK:

```
root@server:~# dotnet --info

Host:
  Version:      7.0.11
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       ecb34f85ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.11 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.11 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Я пытаюсь запустить программу, написанную на .NET но не получается...

Когда я пытаюсь запустить свой сервер, мне пишет это:

```
root@server:~/server# dotnet KOBServer
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'KOBServer' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам SDK на сервере? Почему запустить программу не получается?

Comment: @andreymal без .NET ее не запустить.

Comment: Для запуска нужен не SDK, а Runtime, который у вас вполне установлен. Так почему не получается-то?

Comment: @andreymal я написал команду "dotnet server_game" чтобы запустить сервер. Пишет что не найден .NET SDK

Comment: Что такое server_game, что **конкретно** (а не в вашем пересказе) оно пишет и чем оно обосновывает необходимость наличия SDK?

Comment: @andreymal посмотрите, я исправил вопрос

Comment: Что такое KOBServer и откуда он берётся? Если это exe-файл, то почему вы не указали расширение exe?

Comment: @andreymal это не exe файл. Он был написан на MacBook

Comment: Что выводит команда `file KOBServer` ?

Comment: @andreymal KOBServer: Mach-O 64-bit arm64 executable, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|WEAK_DEFINES|BINDS_TO_WEAK|PIE|HAS_TLV_DESCRIPTORS>

Comment: Ну, маковские файлы совершенно не обязаны запускаться в линуксе. Ищите в своём маке, как сделать линуксовую сборку, что-то типа такого https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: @andreymal я нашел способ опубликовать на windows под linux-x64 Но не нашел как это сделать на MacBook Air. Я использую Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: @Alexey `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64`